# A minimum value question?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, optimization

This is what the original question was: The minimum value of the expression $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C$, where $A$,$B$ and $C$ are real numbers satisfying $A+B+C=\pi$ is

(A) positive (B) zero (C) negative (D) -3

Additionally, how would you find the exact minimum value?

Comment: are $A, B, C$ nonnegative?

Comment: No, the question mentions no restriction.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that there are no restriction on A, B, C.

Clearly the answer cannot be (D) -3 (Why?)

Observe that $ \sin -0.1 + \sin -0.1 + \sin ( \pi + 0.2) < 0 $.

Hence, the answer is (C) negative.

---

(One of the possibilities of) The minimum occurs when $A = B = - \frac{\pi}{3} $, $ C = \frac{ 5 \pi } { 3}$, and the value is $ - \frac{ 3 \sqrt{3} } 2$.

The simplest way out seems to be to set up the Lagrangian (which I'm not happy to do, esp without further context of where your problem is from / the level of material that you are expected to know)

---

If A, B, C are forced to be non-negative, then the answer is zero.

If A, B, C are forced to be positive, then the answer is positive.

Comment: The question was not "what is the exact minimum value?" but "how would you find the exact minimum value?" What was your method?

Comment: The observation comes from a concavity argument. For finding the minimum I'd suggest Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton There are 2 parts to his question. I have not answered the "additionally" part as yet. I'm trying to decide what is the best approach, preferably without lagrangians.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks!